# Copy and Rename Excel ActiveSheet in vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, export

I am generating a command button in access that will export data into Excel. At present, I have this function working and am trying to perfect it a little more such that each export will export the data onto a new sheet which will effectively be a copy of the ActiveSheet. The code that seems to be failing me is:

```
'Open workbook

Excel.Workbooks.Open "\\aos03s-fp04\brewsti2$\Alarms\ExportTest - " & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".xlsx", True, False

'Copy initial activesheet

ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=Excel.Sheets("Sheet2")

'Rename new copied sheet

ActiveSheet.Name = Me.RAW_TAG
```

The code fails on the ActiveSheet.Copy function. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the sheet you are trying to copy it before exist? i.e. Is there a "Sheet2" in your workbook - check spelling/spacing.

Comment: What is the actual error message you're getting?

Comment: The error I am experiencing is: Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.

Answer (score 2):

Access has in build Command button procedure to Export Table to Excel. But, anyway, you can use this one:

```
Dim outputFileName As String
outputFileName = CurrentProject.Path & ".xls"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Table1", outputFileName , True
```

Try this, alternatively:

```
Sub CopySheet()
Dim MySheetName As String 
MySheetName = "TestSheet" Sheets("MasterSheet").Copy After:=Sheets("MasterSheet") 
ActiveSheet.Name = MySheetName
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, alternatively:

```
Sub CopySheet()
Dim MySheetName As String 
MySheetName = "TestSheet" Sheets("MasterSheet").Copy After:=Sheets("MasterSheet") 
ActiveSheet.Name = MySheetName
End Sub
```

Comment: This answer and [one other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43323371/1128918) were added by the same user. I guess they should be merged. The user could have added the alternative answer as an update to the first answer.

Comment: My desired outcome is that the code opens the desired workbook, as is the case and then proceeds to copy the active sheet (of unknown name) and place this after the current sheet or before the last and then rename this sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this code is running in MS Access VBA, and `Excel` is an Excel `Application` object, you need to specify that `ActiveSheet` is a property of that `Application` object:

```
'Open workbook

Excel.Workbooks.Open "\\aos03s-fp04\brewsti2$\Alarms\ExportTest - " & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".xlsx", True, False

'Copy initial activesheet

Excel.ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=Excel.Sheets("Sheet2")

'Rename new copied sheet

Excel.ActiveSheet.Name = Me.RAW_TAG
```